# split one record into two in power bi

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I have the following record:

```
ID                                      Payload
746E2C41-79EE-46E7-8FC4-00958EEA13E2    {"ExtraDetails":{"response":"bad one","err_msg":"No connection"}}
```

The idea here is that payload is a dictionary of <string, string> values. They don't necessarily follow any pattern but rather there are any number of <string,string> pairs in ExtraDetails and they can have any value.

I want to split this record into two records in this case so I get something like this:

```
ID                                      Payload
746E2C41-79EE-46E7-8FC4-00958EEA13E2    "response":"bad one"
746E2C41-79EE-46E7-8FC4-00958EEA13E2    "err_msg":"No connection"
```

I would really like something that can repeat for any number of <string,string> pairs there are inside the ExtraDetails.

Is this something that can be achieved in power bi?

Comment: Expand it and [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column) the data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to achieve the result I wanted with a combination of splitting the column into columns and then row. thanks for taking the time to comment

Comment: The **Payload** is a Json. `Json.Document` will transform it into a `Record`. Then you just need to expand the column twice, and Unpivot.  (If you want it in the same column as you show, you can merge the unpivoted columns.  Or not.  May be more flexible than what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the result I wanted with a combination of splitting the column into columns and then using advance options to change it to rows.